# Explosive lenses and timing: don't the triggers have to be synchronized or do the lenses make the arrangement more forgiving?

Tags: atomic-physics, explosions

I do not know if this is physics or engineering, but it is complex engineering I think at least.

(In the implosion fission bomb first tested at Trinity and used in Nagasaki. Not the gun type.)

A big problem with the implosion design was uneven compression and a member of the British team named Tuck suggested explosive lenses (which had been employed in anti-tank weapons, I think).

Somehow the lenses were supposed to even out the explosive wave but were there not multiple shaped charges in the form of the lenses? And if so, how to ensure the lenses went off at the same time anyway?

Basically, I would like to understand how explosive lenses fixed the implosion problem.

Comment: See [Going Nuclear - Nuclear Science - Part 3 - Plutonium Implosion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ufRzj89VoH4&list=PLYu7z3I8tdEnTQMXpP6gYN9DVm_DjXza9&index=4). The rest of Scott Manley's Going Nuclear series is also worth viewing.

Answer (score 1):

The lenses tended to bring the implosion wave to a common focus. to accomplish this they had to be very precisely synchronized, which required inventing a new way to set off the explosives themselves.